# Serialization/Deserialization of complex types causes segmentation fault in C++

Tags: c++, c, serialization, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to use the simplest way of serialization/deserialization by simply writing the complex types into a binary file in the serialization process and read from the file in case of deserialization.
The complex type in my case is PFC.
This is the function responsible for writing the object to file.

```
void SerializeCurve(const char* file_name, PFC& data) // Writes the 
 given Curve data to the given file name.
{
        ofstream out;
        out.open(file_name,ios::out|ios::binary);
        out.seekp(0);
        out.write((char*)&data, sizeof(PFC));
        out.close();
};
```

And this one reads from the file.

```
void DeserializeCurve(const char* file_name, PFC& data) // Reads the given file and assigns the data to the given OBJECT.
{

    ifstream in;

    in.open(file_name,ios::in|ios::binary);
    in.seekg(0);
    in.read((char*)&data, sizeof(PFC));

    in.close();

};
```

In my main function after debugging I found that when I uses the deserialized object I get the segmentation fault otherwise everything is fine.

```
int main()
 {

  Big test;
  PFC pfc(AES_SECURITY);  /* initialise pairing-friendly curve*/
  /*TODO: Serialize pfc and send it */
  test=pfc.order();
  cout << "first order" << test << endl;
  PFC pfc2(90);
  SerializeCurve("Curve.bin",pfc);

  /*Test part*/
  DeserializeCurve("Curve.bin",pfc2);
  test=pfc2.order(); // THIS CAUSES THE SEGMENTATION FAULT
  cout << "second order " << test<< endl;


  return 0;
  }
```

As I mentionned `test=pfc2.order();` causes the seg fault.
PS: for serialization I cannot use the boost library because I'm not allowed to modify the PFC object declaration.
Any idea to fix this?

Comment: Why do you feel it is necessary to seek?

Comment: to avoid any problem that can occurs

Comment: You cannot `write` a complex data structure. Figure out why for yourself. Hint: if you could, no one would need boost::serialisation.

Comment: "to avoid any problem" what kind of problem?

Comment: I tried to write complex data in binary file using the same way but for another example and it worked I don't know why this time is not the case.

Comment: Either it didn't really work, or it wasn't really complex.

Comment: Hopefully you do know enough about C++ to understand that `sizeof()` is a compile-time constant, that gives the size of the structure, that never changes, right? Given that, what do you think are the chances of successfully writing the contents of a `std::string` to a file, simply by doing what you're doing, and somehow ending up with the right results, using the same constant `sizeof()`, whether the string is empty, or contains the entire contents of "War & Peace"?

Comment: What does your `PFC` class look like?

Comment: This code will only work if PFC is a POD

Comment: The PFC is 'really complex' actually it's composed of other complex objects